# Disable ctrl-b keyboard shortcut in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

As a tmux user, there is a lot of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> going on. Also a lot of Firefox.

It's safe to say I never, ever want to see the book mark vertical bar. No interest. Never had any in 20 years of computer use.

Is there any way to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> in Firefox without using a plug-in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been able to disable the `Ctrl+B` shortcut by using the [Shortkeys](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/shortkeys/) extension.

Its configuration can be a little cumbersome, so here's a quick guide:

- In the extensions page (`about:addons`), click the `...` menu next to the Shortkeys entry, and select "Preferences"
- Add a new shortcut:

  - In the "Shortcut" column, type "Ctrl+B".
  - In the "Label" column, enter something like "Disable bookmarks sidebar".
  - In the "Behavior" column, select the "Do nothing" entry
- Don’t foget to click the <kbd>Save shortcuts</kbd> button at the bottom of the page!

**Note:** This only works in the context of a web page. The default Firefox action will still execute if you press `Ctrl+B` while the cursor is e.g. in the URL bar or the search bar. But for me it's a great improvement already!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for macOS. I have tried all three options: "Ctrl+B", "Cmd+B", "Command+B"

Answer (score 1):

Since Firefox 72, this needs to be done with autoconfig.js.  See [Firefox documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-autoconfig) and [example usage](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=14854175&sid=390a8f705ab212acc29d72f1414caa73#p14854175).

OLD WAY: This can be accomplished using [userChrome.js](https://github.com/nuchi/firefox-quantum-userchromejs)

Use the following code:

```
var key = document.getElementById('viewBookmarksSidebarKb');
if (key) key.remove();
```

Credit - I found this thanks to this answer https://superuser.com/questions/1318336/how-to-disable-ctrlq-shortcut-in-firefox-on-linux/1348082#1348082

Comment: Unfortunately, since Firefox 72 (January 2020) this option doesn't work anymore :(

Comment: @waldyrious Thanks for adding the comment.  It still works using a slightly different way so I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I realise in the original question is the qualifier "without a plugin", however my answer is helpful to those without that restriction. I've found a way to do this using a Greasemonkey script in Firefox for macOS.

Firstly, install the [Greasemonkey Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox and give it the appropriate permissions (e.g. “Run in Private Windows” if desired). Then add the following “New user script…”:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Disable “Bookmarks Sidebar” keyboard shortcut
// @description    Disables the Ctrl+B and Cmd+B keyboard shortcuts in Firefox
// @version        1
// @grant          none
// ==/UserScript==

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.metaKey && event.keyCode == 66) { //macOS: Checks if Cmd and B are pressed
    event.preventDefault(); //Blocks default event handler
  }
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 66) { //Windows: Checks if Ctrl and B are pressed
    event.preventDefault(); //Blocks default event handler
  }
}, false);
```

In the above code, the keyboard key "B" corresponds with the number 66, but you could of course change this for other keyboard shortcuts too.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work if the URL address bar, or the search box, are selected. But it does work after webpages have loaded, or if any elements are clicked on within the webpage. So this is a workaround / partial solution.

Answer (score -1):

Many topics on this and none seem to work, so I've just hand-rolled something that does seem to work. This is JavaScript-only, with no try/catch blocks for clarity.

Goal: In contentEditable DIV, prevent Firefox from processing Ctrl-B, so we can use it to set the text content to BOLD.

Basic idea is to stop propagation at the body (suppress bubble up to browser), while setting bold at the control (allowing bubble-down to text that is being edited in the div). Solution is FF-only, since that is the question, but I can extend it to Webkit and IE on request.

HTML:

```html
<body onkeydown="bodyKeyHandler(this, event);">
    <div contentEditable="true" onkeydown="editorKeyHandler(event);"></div>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```js
function bodyKeyHandler(o,e) {
    var c = e.ctrlKey;
    var k = e.which;
    if (e.ctrlKey) { 
        switch ( k ) {
            case 17:
                e.preventDefault();
                o.stopPropagation();
                break;
        }
    }
}

function editorKeyHandler(e) {
    var c = e.ctrlKey;
    var k = e.which;
    if (c) { 
        switch ( k ) {
            case 17:
                document.execCommand("bold");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

One important warning, when fiddling with this in FF, injecting alert() to see what's happening will break it, because the alert popup will capture and bubble the event to the browser! To see it working, remove all tracing.

Comment: This only works when in a web page that has code like this to bind the `Ctrl+B` shortcut using JavaScript. This is the case, for instance, in StackOverflow and GitHub text boxes (try focusing the answer box below and pressing Ctrl+B to see it in action). However, the original question is about disabling the `Ctrl+B` shortcut across the browser, regardless of the page one's in and what element is currently focused. This solution, unfortunately does not do that.